# CallKit: Add number to blocking list of CXCallDirectoryProvider

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I want to add number to blocking list, while using my application.

Currently, I am trying to update the blocking list, but its not working

```
 let callDirectoryExtensionContext = CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext.init()
    let phoneNumbers: [CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber] = [ xx_xxx_xxx_xxxx ]
    for phoneNumber in phoneNumbers {
        callDirectoryExtensionContext.addBlockingEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: phoneNumber)
    }


    let callDirectoryProvider = CXCallDirectoryProvider.init()
    callDirectoryProvider.beginRequest(with: callDirectoryExtensionContext)

    CXCallDirectoryManager.sharedInstance.reloadExtension(withIdentifier: "com.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.CustomCallDirectoryProvider") { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Is it possible with CallKit, to update or add numbers to blocking list.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make those types of calls arbitrarily in your app.  You must do it by creating an extension target in Xcode, implementing the CXCallDirectoryProvider protocol, and implementing the beginRequest callback.   This is then called when iOS determines your extension needs to be loaded or reloaded.

You will want to read [Apple's App Extension guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214).

Comment: I have implemented  CXCallDirectoryProvider extension, which is called when application is launched, but I want to reload the extension so that I can update list of contacts to be blocked, during the running lifecycle application.

Comment: Doesn't calling `reloadExtension(withIdentifier` work?